# XmlSerializer replace xsi:type to node name

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-serialization

Currently XmlSerializer produces the following structure:

```
<config>
  <BaseType xsi:type="DerivedType1" />
  <BaseType xsi:type="DerivedType2" />
</config>
```

Is there any way to make it put type name into node:

```
<config>
  <DerivedType1 />
  <DerivedType2 />
</config>
```

?

Comment: Can you provide the code of the class you want to serialize ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can just override the element name with the XmlElement Attrribute e.g.

```
[XmlElement("DerivedType1")]
public BaseType : DerivedType1 {get;set;}
```

if will still put the xsi:type in though, and generate even greater confusion...

What does your class look like?

Comment: I don't want to override element name. I want serializer to set the Name equal to class name

Comment: That is what this answer intents to do.

Comment: It will do that. As far as I know you can't suppress the typing, because then you'd never be able to deserialise. If you don't need to deserialise, then you aren't serialising, therefore you should stop messing abouyt with serialisation and simply write a dumptoxml method for your class. Serialisation has rules, if you don't follow them, you aren't doing it...

Comment: -, `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute` cannot be put on classes, and classes don't have direct `getters and setters (properties have them). this code does not compile ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair What are you on about? Who put it on a class? You by any chance?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Arr, fair enough ... `BaseType : DerivedType1` made me think this was a class definition ... Anyway, this code does not compile, could you possible fix it, so that I can remove my downvote?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Not much point really Tamir Daniely should have got the acceptance, and I'd just be inventing a load of scaffolding useless to anyone else.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson that `: DerivedType1` is useless (as the hierarchy is defined in the question) and breaks the validity of the code. Additionally, your solution does not provide an example of how to work with multiple descendant types and their potential different xml-tags. just sayin' ...

Answer (score 29):

Use the `XmlElementAttribute` constructor overload `(string elementName, Type type)`.
It allows you to replace the element name given the actual type found in the member.
Stack several of these together if you have multiple derived types.

If you are trying to serialize a generic collection like `List<Base>` that might contain instances of Derived then use the `XmlArrayItem` in the same way.

Defining in this way also implicitly makes the derived type known, So an `XmlInclude` attribute is not required

Sample definition:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("Derived1", typeof(Derived1))]
    [XmlElement("Derived2", typeof(Derived2))]
    public Base foo { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayItem("Derived1", typeof(Derived1))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Derived2", typeof(Derived2))]
    public List<Base> fooList { get; set; }
}

public class Base { ... }
public class Derived1 : Base { ... }
public class Derived2 : Base { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do people keep saying "you'll never be able to deserialize."
That is definitionally FALSE.

```
public class BaseClass {
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
[XmlRoot("BaseClass")]
public class ChildClass : BaseClass {
  public int Value {get;set;}
}
[XmlRoot("BaseClass")]
public class FlatClass
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Value {get;set;}
}

XmlSerializer ser1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseClass));
XmlSerializer ser2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ChildClass));
XmlSerializer ser3 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FlatClass));
ser1.Serialize(File.Open("ser1.xml", FileMode.Create), new BaseClass(){Name="Base"});
ser2.Serialize(File.Open("ser2.xml", FileMode.Create), new ChildClass(){Name="Child",Value = 1});

ser1.Deserialize(File.OpenRead("ser2.xml"));
ser2.Deserialize(File.OpenRead("ser1.xml"));
ser3.Deserialize(File.OpenRead("ser2.xml"));
```

Boom. Works just FINE!!!!!
Serialization goes all three both ways perfectly.  the resulting objects may not be 100% on either side, but it DOES deserialize.
Ser1 IGNORES the Value element when deserializing ser2.xml 
Ser2 SKIPS the Value propertuy when deserializing ser1.xml

The only thing that breaks this model is:

```
ser1.Serailize(File.Open("ser3.xml", FileMode.Create), new ChildClass(){Name = "Child2", Value = 2});
XmlSerialize ser3 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FlatClass));
ser3.Deserialize(File.OpenRead("ser3.xml"));
```

This last breaks, becuase the the Serializer for the BaseClass follows the schema standard (albeit a valuable and 99% of the time desired standard) of including the xsi:type="ChildClass" attribute on the  element. Ser3 cannot process that type because it is not realated to that type, especially if FlatClass exists in another assembly across WAN or LAN lines.
Just like the Honey-badger the XmlSerailizer DON'T CARE about the elements or values as long as it can find them and nothing in the schema breaks the process.  The XSI:TYPE attribute breaks the schema.

Like, for instance, when using WCF or other XML communication based systems if the Service has a class called FlatClass, it WILL NOT DESERIALIZE a ChildClass that contains the xsi:type="" attribute.  However, if you don't use the serializer for the BaseClass, it WILL deserialize the exact same XML without that xsi:type attribute.

Q.E.D.
It is often times beneficial, necessary, and DESIRABLE, to **NOT** include the xsi:type attribute.

So with that being said is there a way to have an XmlSerializer created for the BaseClass type and tell it NOT to include the xsi:type attribute when serializing a child type?

Thanks
Jaeden "Sifo Dyas" al'Raec Ruiner