# Can the serializer be forced to not generate the xsi:type attribute?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

When serializing an object with a polymorphic member, the xml element representing this member automatically receives the xsi:type attribute specifying the name of the actual type.
In theory, this can help in deserialization, but unfortunately it is often the opposite, as mentioned here (question is unrelated, take a look at the JaedenRuiner's answer): [XmlSerializer replace xsi:type to node name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359979/xmlserializer-replace-xsitype-to-node-name/31441599#31441599)

In my case, I need to send my serialized object to an external application that has a completely different architecture and the type name I use can bring nothing but confusion there.

Sample classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Bar
{ }

public class Baz : Bar
{ }
```

and serialization:

```
public void FooTest()
{
    var foo = new Foo { Bar = new Baz() };

    var xDoc = new XDocument();

    XmlSerializer objSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo), new System.Type[] { typeof(Baz) });
    using (XmlWriter writer = xDoc.CreateWriter())
    {
        objSerializer.Serialize(writer, foo);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(xDoc.Root);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Result:

```
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Bar xsi:type="Baz" />
</Foo>
```

**Can I somehow stop generating of this `xsi:type="Baz"` attribute?**

Comment: You can, I am not going to retype what they have typed out already:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729711/prevent-xmlserializer-from-emitting-xsitype-on-inherited-types  and to remove the namespaces (if you want):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760262/xmlserializer-remove-unnecessary-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces

Comment: @Epistaxis I thought about sub-classing the writer, but I was wondering if there was no simpler solution. On the other hand, having own writter gives me almost full flexibility.

Comment: The other option would be to use `XmlAttributeOverrides`.  But there's no easy way to do this because `XmlSerializer` is designed to round-trip models without data loss, and stripping the `xsi:type` tag means loss of polymorphic type information.  For more see [Using XmlSerializer to serialize derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643424/3744182).